# Exception when I try to deserialize an object with a List<>

Tags: c#, json, list

I've a simple class written in this way:

```cs
public class SamplingItemModel {
        public List<SamplingTestModel>    SamplesTests;
        public string IdCategory;
}
```

```cs
public class SamplingTestModel {
        public string IdSample;
}
```

When I get the json from Server and I try to deserialize it with *JsonConvert.DeserializeObject* ( I'm using Newtonsoft ), I get an Expception:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SamplingItemModel>( resultContent );
```

```
ErrorMessage: The value "EusoftApp.SamplingTestModel" is not of type 
"EusoftApp.SamplingItemModel" and cannot be used in this generic collection.
```

But why *SamplesTests* should be a *SamplingItemModel*? It not make sense to me.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Hey can we have a look at your json file ?

Comment: Have you tried copying the json to your clipboard and then Paste as Json Classes from VS?   Then it will create the correct classes and their properties

Comment: I strongly suggest https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp .

Comment: The classes should also use public properties instead of fields.

Comment: @GaetanoLenoci Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or additional details to highlight exactly what was done, it’s hard to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Comment: I see, I'm creating a json without "sensible" informations.

Answer (score -1):

My guess would be you have the class names the wrong way around.
`SamplingTestModel` sounds like the parent class name and `SamplingItemModel` sounds like an item in the list.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SamplingItemModel.SampleTests>( resultContent );
```